# How to query on nested foreign keys in KnexJS + bookshelf

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I use knexJS and bookshelf ORM for my nodejs application. The problem is, when a record ID is given, I need to query for getting list of its "great-grandchildren" records. There are thousands of hundreds records in the destination table, so page number and size are also supposed to pass as params and I need to sort it out via query. Doing filter after getting all records is not a solution.

Let me explain the relationships between models.

```
// MenuItem model
module.exports = (Model, models) => {
  return Model.extend({
    tableName: 'menu_items',
    menu_day() {
      return this.belongsTo(models.MenuDay);
    },
  });
};
```

This is `MenuItem` model I am gonna get list for. As you see, it's related to `MenuDay` model via foreign key.

```
// MenuDay model
module.exports = (Model, models) => {
  return Model.extend({
    tableName: 'menu_days',
    menu_items() {
      return this.hasMany(models.MenuItem);
    },
    menu() {
      return this.belongsTo(models.Menu);
    }
  });
};
```

`MenuDay` model is related to `Menu` model via foreign key.

```
// Menu model
module.exports = (Model, models) => {
  return Model.extend({
    tableName: 'menus',
    menu_days() {
      return this.hasMany(models.MenuDay);
    },
    restaurant() {
      return this.belongsTo(models.Restaurant);
    }
  });
};
```

`Menu` model is related to `Restaurant` and a restaurant ID is just given as an input for this position.

```
// Restaurant model
module.exports = (Model, models) => {
  return Model.extend({
    tableName: 'restaurants',
    menus() {
      return this.hasMany(models.Menu);
    }
  });
};
```

I tried tremendous solutions for sorting this out but lost a couple of days of mine in this problem.
Whatever it is, any help would be highly appreciated! You will save my life.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to get in practice?

Comment: @devius I want to get menu items associated with a restaurant when its ID is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could sort this out myself using Knex only, not Bookshelf.

```js
knex.raw(`
 SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE menu_day_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM menu_days WHERE menu_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM menus WHERE restaurant_id = ?
  )
 ) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
`, [restaurantId, limit, (page - 1) * limit])
.then(res => {
  const menuItems = res.rows;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withRelated` option of `fetch()` for that:

```
new Restaurant({id: 1}).fetch({
  withRelated: ['menus.menu_days.menu_items']
}).then(restaurant => {
  const menus = restaurant.related('menus')
  const menuDays = menus.related('menu_days')
  const menuItems = menuDays.related('menu_items')
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I wanna get menu items, not menus under the restaurant